# Font stack from SCSS to LESS?

Tags: css, sass, less

How would I write this code in LESS, from SCSS? The error it gives is "Selector matches unknown element font-stack".

```
$font-stack: 'Raleway', 'Helvetica Neue', Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
$font-stack-body: 'Open Sans', Trebuchet, Tahoma, sans-serif;

$color-primary: #ff7200;
$color-primary-light: #f90;
$color-primary-dark: #e51;
$color-secondary: #005790;
$color-secondary-light: #0072bc;
$color-secondary-dark: #00384a;
```

Comment: You need to use `@` to declare variables in LESS .. like `@font-stack: 'Raleway', 'Helvetica Neue', Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly, as Mr Alien said, you should  do

```
@font-stack: 'Raleway', 'Helvetica Neue', Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
@font-stack-body: 'Open Sans', Trebuchet, Tahoma, sans-serif;

@color-primary: #ff7200;
@color-primary-light: #f90;
@color-primary-dark: #e51;
@color-secondary: #005790;
@color-secondary-light: #0072bc;
@color-secondary-dark: #00384a;
```